# python: how to do an if/else to read in a csv that can be empty

Tags: python, pandas

i want to create a try/except or an if/else statement to create dataframes based on an input csv. but it is possible for the input csv to be blank/empty so if i do a blanket `pd.read_csv(file_name)`
it will throw an error when the csv is empty.

how can i do this so that:

```
if pd.read_csv(file_name) is successful:
   new_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
else:
   new_df = pd.DataFrame() # to set this as an empty data frame
```

i previously tried:

```
try:
    new_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
except:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame() # to set this as an empty data frame
```

this did not work because it always set new_df to an empty df even if the csv was not empty

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to read an empty CSV with `pandas.read_csv` raises a `pandas.errors.EmptyDataError` exception, so you can catch that specifically

```
import pandas as pd


try:
    df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exceptions with `try/except`:

```
try:
   new_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
except SomePandasError:  # replace this with the actual exception
   new_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

The `except` will *only* happen if the specified exception type is raised.  If you did a bare `try/except` and you were always getting a blank dataframe, it means that an exception is *always* being raised -- make sure to only catch the exception that you expect (i.e. the one raised on an empty CSV) so that if you hit some other error it will raise as normal and you can figure out how to fix it.